# Loop with a Loop including an explode()

Tags: php, loops, nested-loops

I have an associative array returning a SQL query that pulls questions from my database. The tags field is stored as a delimited text VarChar.  I want to loop through all of my database entries while using explode to create an array and then loop through the tag array to create a UL with the tags as well unfortunately it has not worked very well. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php foreach($questionRow as $questionShow) { ?>
    <?php echo ($questionShow['netvotes']) ;?>
    <?php echo ($questionShow['views']) ;?>
    <?php echo ($questionShow['q_answer_count']) ;?>
    <?php echo ($questionShow['title']) ;?>
    Tags:
    <ul style="display: inline">
        <?php
            $tagname = explode(",",$questionShow['tags']);
            foreach ($tagname as $tagList) {  ?>
                <li class="label label-inverse" style="margin-left: 5px"><?php echo($tagList) ;?></li>
        <?php }; ?>
    </ul>
<?php }; ?>
```

The results were very strange

I also tried by using the below to run my outer loop

```
<?php while($questionShow =$questionResult>fetch_assoc() ) { ?>
```

That caused the main recordset results to not actually loop.  Hopefully I have explained this properly and someone could help.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: `$questionResult>fetch_assoc()` is wrong.

Comment: Can you please detail *The results were very strange*?

Comment: My apology I forgot to mention I am using the meegroDB library.  That explains the shorter fetch_assoc() vs mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: Also in regards to how the results displayed, I think an image is the best explanation http://i.imgur.com/VmKqm32.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this could be very simple:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` LIMIT 30"); // replace this with your query
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $data['netvotes'];
    echo $data['views'];
    echo $data['q_answer_count'];
    echo $data['title']) ;?>
?>
Tags:
<ul style="display: inline">
    <?php
         foreach(explode(",",$data['tags']) as $tag){
    ?>
            <li class="label label-inverse" style="margin-left: 5px"><?php echo $tag; ?></li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```